# Trouble creating SQL queries - Beginner

Tags: sql, erd

I've created the linked ERD for some university work but SQL is the one thing that just hasn't been sticking. I am required to list the id, first name, last name, telephone and address of all members who have made more than one purchase, ensuring I add an appropriate alias when retrieving the details for all members.

ERD link -
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD6C0.png

My attempt is below. Is this correct? Can I add individual aliases to each member detail? Can I use "WHERE purchaseTotal" if purchases aren't a part of the member table?

```
SELECT (memberId AS 'ID', memberFirstName AS 'First Name', memberLastName AS 'Last Name',
        memberAddress AS 'Address', memberPhone AS 'Phone')
FROM Member
WHERE purchaseTotal > 1;
```

Comment: You don't need to put aliases between the apostrophes. Just write memberId as Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very basic terms, you can use only that column in a query, which is present in the tables being queried.

So in your query above, you are using `purchaseTotal` column, but that is not available in `Member` table. So you need to add `Purchases` table as well.

The query should be

```
SELECT Members.memberId AS 'ID', memberFirstName AS 'First Name', memberLastName AS 'Last Name', memberAddress AS 'Address', memberPhone AS 'Phone'
FROM Purchases
LEFT JOIN Members ON Purchases.memberId = Members.memberId
WHERE purchaseTotal > 1;
```

**Note** :

For all the columns that are common in both the tables, you need to specify from which table you need to display the column. Ex, `Members.memberId`

Answer (score 0):

You are running to the column named purchaseTotal but you are not looking for it in the correct table. purchaseTotal belong to Purchases table.

if you want to get a value from purchaseTotal column, you should use correct table.

```
select * from purchases where purchaseTotal > 1;
```

Or you should use "join":

```
SELECT *
FROM Member
INNER JOIN Purchases ON Purchases.memberID=Member.memberID
WHERE Purchases.purchaseTotal > 1;
```